# How to aproach painting/changing texture dynamically

Tags: texture-painting, dynamic-paint

I was wondering, if I for example have animated guy that is painting fence. How should I make it look like he is actually painting it? Like only after every stroke, the fence would change color. But I don't think texture change is the right approach. Any suggestions?

Comment: you can do this with [dynamic paint](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/dynamic_paint/index.html) Watch:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PcWXFtnh2bk